# The best way to return a matched expression

Tags: pattern-matching

I need to store or use a matched pattern, as I need it later on. I'd like it so that the match is NOT confined in a pattern-like syntax like:

```
pattern /; test
lhs :> rhs /; test
lhs := rhs /; test
```

or

```
pattern ? test
```

So I've been using this:

```
MatchQ[expr, x:pattern /; (var = x; True)]
```

Is there a neater way to do it, like:

```
var = MatchQ[expr, x:pattern extracode]
```

Comment: I suspect that you meant `var==x`. Could you provide a simple example of some inputs and the desired outputs?

Comment: I then use var. If I want a return mechanism in a function (which has a Block or Module inside), I return var.

Comment: Would `Cases` perhaps do what you have in mind?

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to discern from your question what you're actually trying to do.  Daniel mentioned [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), and maybe you could use that.  If not you could use a utility function in a [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) like this:

```
set = (var = #; True) &;

MatchQ[{1, 2, 3}, (x : _List)?set]

var
```

> ```
> True
>
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```

This particular pattern could also be written concisely as `x_List?set`.

Also consider [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html):

```
sow = (Sow@#; True) &;

MatchQ[{1, 2, 3}, (x : _List)?sow] // Reap
```

> ```
> {True, {{{1, 2, 3}}}}
> ```